# Flash Builder vs Flexbuilder 3 for Actionscript only projects

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

Right now Flexbuilder 3 is my editor of choice for all as3, xml ,js editing.

I'm not 100% convinced that I need to upgrade to FlashBuilder. Also early betas seemed a bit sluggish compared to Flexbuilder3.

Does anyone who has made the upgrade have any convincing reasons? Was it worth it?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your comment about performance, I personally think it feels snappier than FB3. I have actually been using it for quite a while, and am really liking the small things, e.g.:

- Abbreviated type and variable lookup: Typing `TFAS` will auto-complete TextFieldAutoSize. Same goes for `hEF`, which will auto-complete `handleEnterFrame()` (if you have created such a method.)
- Vector auto-completion: If `myVector` is a `Vector.<DisplayObject>`, typing for example `myVector[0].tra` will now complete `myVector[0].transform`.
- Cmd/Ctrl + O will open an outline view similar to FDT's quick outline. The abbreviated lookup works in this view as well.

And of course, the bigger stuff includes improved navigator panel/package explorer, profiler and Flash CS5 integration.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Have you tried the new SourceMate plugin? Are FlashBuilder projects reverse compatible with Flexbuilder 3...or is it one way only (ie from FB3 to Flash Builder?

Comment: @eco_back I have tried SourceMate, and have it installed. It's nice, but not a game-changer in my view.